# Polymer Gestures - Pinch Event (0.4.2)

Tags: javascript, mobile, polymer

On this page:
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures
it says that the "pinch" gesture should already be developed but other ones like hold, holdpulse and release shouldn't, playing with the provided sample:
http://polymer.github.io/polymer-gestures/samples/simple/index.html
I cannot recreate the pinch gesture no matter what, but hold, holdpulse and release keep coming out quite easily, do you know what can be the case?

I've created a simple jsfiddle but it's quite hard to use it on a mobile:

```
<div on-pinch="{{pinchAction}}" on-tap="{{tapAction}}">{{txt}}</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLT5G/77/

I'm using Google Nexus 5.0 either with most recent Chrome or Chrome Beta.

Thanks!

PS In this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lhwc6woa/
I cannot get any events coming from the second finger, so I guess that's why pinch doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a temporary issue, it works at the moment, you can check that out using a jsfiddle attached above.